# Arrange charts position in 3x5 order

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have the following problem. Thank you in advance for the help -

I am trying to arrange 7 charts[Doughnut] in a 3x4 fashion i.e., I want 3 columns and 4 rows of the charts. Below is what my code is printing in excel worksheet.
[image]

I want it printed in this fashion:

[image]

This is the code that I have:

```
        Const TopAnchor As Long = 8
        Const LeftAnchor As Long = 140
        Const HorizontalSpacing As Long = 3
        Const VerticalSpacing As Long = 3
        Const ChartHeight As Long = 125
        Const ChartWidth As Long = 210 

        Dim Counter As Long
        Counter = 0 Counter = Counter + 1

        With ActiveChart.Parent
            .Top = TopAnchor + (WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Counter / 3, 0) - 1) * (VerticalSpacing + ChartHeight)
            .Left = LeftAnchor + ((Counter) Mod 4) * (HorizontalSpacing + ChartWidth)
            .Height = 125
            .Width = 200
        End With
```

Comment: Pretty hard to get three columns and four rows of charts with only 7 charts to work with...

Comment: @pgSystemTester The fourth row has only one chart not all columns have four charts. QED

Comment: okay Shakespeare... nobody knows what that means but glad it works. I was actually pleased how it ended up and it may be one of my better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was almost there. I felt an additional constant needed of `numChartsPerRow`.  I also separated the calculation of row and column,  as they weren't quite ideal. They are done in advance just for illustration when debugging, but could be done within the same lines of  `.Top =` or `.Left=`

Fun question. And my answer was less than a minute behind Tim's.....

```
Sub adjustCharts()
    Const numChartsPerRow = 3
    Const TopAnchor = 8
    Const LeftAnchor = 140
    Const HorizontalSpacing = 3
    Const VerticalSpacing = 3
    Const ChartHeight = 125
    Const ChartWidth = 210

    Dim ws As Worksheet, Counter As Long, zChartSet As ChartObject, _
    colPos As Long, rowNumber As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet '<--- your worksheet

    For Each zChartSet In ws.ChartObjects
        rowNumber = Int(Counter / numChartsPerRow)
        colPos = Counter Mod numChartsPerRow

        With zChartSet
            .Top = TopAnchor + rowNumber * (VerticalSpacing + ChartHeight)
            .Left = LeftAnchor + colPos * (HorizontalSpacing + ChartWidth)
            .Height = ChartHeight
            .Width = ChartWidth
        End With

       Counter = Counter + 1
    Next zChartSet
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Jrules80 great, thanks for accepting. It is a pretty clean solution the more I look at it. You had a good foundation to get there.

Answer (score 4):

You can separate out the positioning logic to make it more re-useable:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim i As Long, shp As Object, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.DrawingObjects.Delete
    
    For i = 1 To 7
        Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart2()
        shp.Height = 125 'better to separate sizing from positioning
        shp.Width = 210
        PositionObjectInGrid shp, i
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub PositionObjectInGrid(obj As Object, objNum As Long)
    Const TopAnchor As Long = 8           'Top starting point
    Const LeftAnchor As Long = 140        'Left starting point
    Const PerRow As Long = 3              '# of items per row
    Const HorizontalSpacing As Long = 3   'Margins...
    Const VerticalSpacing As Long = 3
    With obj
        .Top = TopAnchor + Application.Floor((objNum - 1) / PerRow, 1) * _
                            (obj.Height + VerticalSpacing)
        .Left = LeftAnchor + ((objNum - 1) Mod PerRow) * _
                            (obj.Width + HorizontalSpacing)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With an adjustment this works to create a stack of 7 one for each day of the week. Useful for my smart meter readings.