# Excel graph VBA with varying columns

Tags: excel, vba, graph

[This is how the data looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENX3w.png)
I'm trying to create a code so to get automatic graphs from my data, the first columns (X values) do not change, however the y values change.
Edit: I want to make a graph of B vs D, B vs I and so on (hence the 5*j+4 condition)
I tried this code based on (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_p8hltGY4s) however it gives me one graphs with many series instead of several graphs for my specific condition 5*j+4. which are the only columns I need to produce a graphs for

Any recommendations on how to make this work?

```
Dim FC As Integer
Dim Columncount As Integer
Columncount = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

FC = 0
For j = 2 To Columncount
    For c = 0 To 10
        If j <> FC Then
        FC = (5 * c + 4)
        Else
        FC = FC
        If j = FC Then
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                With .SeriesCollection(1)
                .Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
                Cells(1, j).Address
                .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
                Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(5500, 2)).Address
                .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
                Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(5500, j)).Address
                End With
            .HasLegend = False
            End With
            Else
            End If
            End If
    Next c
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of logic going on with FC which might be much easier to follow if you use  `For x To y Step Z` ?  Or at least tell/show us how your data is laid out and which parts you want to plot.

Comment: I added an image of the data and explained it a bit more.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: added arranging charts in a grid.

Like this maybe:

```vb
Sub Plots()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet, rngX As Range, rngY As Range, ws As Worksheet, n As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'for example
    Set rngX = ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) 'x values
    Set rngY = rngX.EntireRow.Columns("D")   'first Y range
    
    ws.DrawingObjects.Delete
    
    Do While Application.CountA(rngY) > 0  'while have any Y values
        n = n + 1
        With ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .Parent.Height = 150    '  .Parent = chartobject
            .Parent.Width = 150
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .name = ws.Cells(1, rngY.Column).value
                .XValues = rngX
                .values = rngY
            End With
            .HasLegend = False
            PositionObjectInGrid .Parent, n
        End With
        
        Set rngY = rngY.Offset(0, 5) '5 columns to the right
    Loop

End Sub

Sub PositionObjectInGrid(obj As Object, objNum As Long)
    Const TopAnchor As Long = 100           'Top starting point
    Const LeftAnchor As Long = 50        'Left starting point
    Const PerRow As Long = 3              '# of items per row
    Const HorizontalSpacing As Long = 3   'Margins...
    Const VerticalSpacing As Long = 3
    With obj
        .Top = TopAnchor + Application.Floor((objNum - 1) / PerRow, 1) * _
                            (obj.Height + VerticalSpacing)
        .Left = LeftAnchor + ((objNum - 1) Mod PerRow) * _
                            (obj.Width + HorizontalSpacing)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried your code and the same thing happens, I get several graphs that have all the data (from column B until the last) as different series.

Comment: I need the graphs of B vs D to be separate than B vs I and so on

Comment: That doesn't do that?  you'll need to write some code to position the charts so they're not stacked on top of each other. Eg see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962481/arrange-charts-position-in-3x5-order/75962656#75962656